# WARN DefaultAddResource - MyFaces special javascript could not be retrieved from request-map

Tags: jsf, weblogic, myfaces

My application worked perfectly on Tomcat 7.x server, but when I  had migrated to the WebLogic 12c it stopped working correctly. Deploying is done successfuly, but all `h:commandButton` doesn't  work. Also I'm using  Apache MyFaces tomahawk for uploading files. And when I press some `h:commandButton` nothing happens only one record appears in logs:

```
WARN  DefaultAddResource:363 - MyFaces special javascript could not be retrieved from request-map.
```

I tried to remove all MyFaces elements from my project but result still the same, only without record in logs.

Comment: WebLogic has JSF bundled, Tomcat not. Did you take this difference into account?

Comment: No, I didn't. What should I do or where can I learn what I should do?

Comment: Remove JSF API/impl JARs (not Tomahawk!) from your webapp and retry. An alternative would be to reconfigure/instruct WebLogic somehow to use webapp-supplied JSF API/impl instead of the WebLogic-supplied ones. I can answer this from top of head for Glassfish and JBoss, but not for WebLogic.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help me. But I noticed one interesting feature: when my application is deploys on the server, in server console exists notice, which said that my application have started on PrimeFaces 3.5 with using `org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent`. I tried to override it in faces-config.xml but it didn't help. When I tried change mojarra elements on Primefaces elements, all works like it should. But I want it to work with a standart EventListener.

Answer (score 0):

*As of WebLogic Server 12.1.1, JSF 2.x and JSTL 1.2 have been incorporated directly in the server's classpath*

This link will tell you how to reconfigure your application to disable the bundled JSF that is shipped with Weblogic 12c.

I'm still hoping to find a way to disable the bundled JSF directly in weblogic without having to reconfigure each and every application that is deployed to our servers.

From Using JSF and JSTL - 12c Release 1 (12.1.1):
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/configurejsfandjtsl.htm

If your application includes JSF JARs that you want to reference instead of the WebLogic Server bundled JSF shared libraries, you can configure a filtering classloader in weblogic.xml (.war) or weblogic-application.xml (.ear) as shown below:

```
<prefer-application-packages> 
   <package-name>javax.faces.*</package-name> 
   <package-name>com.sun.faces.*</package-name> 
   <package-name>com.bea.faces.*</package-name> 
   </prefer-application-packages> 

   <prefer-application-resources> 
   <resource-name>javax.faces.*</resource-name> 
   <resource-name>com.sun.faces.*</resource-name> 
   <resource-name>com.bea.faces.*</resource-name> 

<resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</resource-name>
   </prefer-application-resources>
```